# Free todo software that allows repeat tasks both on given dates and on arbitrary timeframes

Tags: gratis, todo

I am looking for a free todo software that lets me set repeatable tasks both by date (1st of every month, January 1st every year) and more arbitrary timeframes (daily, seven days from prior completion, every 3 days). Preferably libre as well as gratis.

Answer (score 0):

Not libre, but [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) allows you to create task lists with repeating reminders, which are synced with Google Calendar.